# Why does my iPad keep trying to reply to ancient comments on SE chat?

Tags: bug, mobile-web, android, mobile-safari, ios

In the SE chat rooms in which I am most active, whenever I log in or refresh the page, it the message box appears with :1234567 or whatever already filled in.  It is trying to reply to comments from quite some time ago.  The message ID number is different from room to room, but it happens in almost every room.

I have deleted cookies, restarted, etc, all to no avail.  Mobile Safari on iOS 9.1, The url seems correct - no message ID number or anything.

How can I reset this or is it a feature/bug?

Comment: Aha, this happens to me on Android (Chrome) all the time too. (I never bothered to report the bug.)

Comment: FWIW - the sessions for Capy Stenchbeast were cleared by me before this was migrated here.

Comment: This happens on both my accounts, if that matters.

Comment: In one word: Caching.